# collecting data from checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, wizard, checkboxlist

Pretty basic question, I have a checkboxlist inside of a wizard control.  I need to collect the value of all items that are checked, as well as whatever value is inside of a textbox if "other" is checked, to insert into my database during the Wizard.FinishButtonClick event.  How do I do this?  I need this in VB, please.

Comment: You should have done some basic research about your task. You will get lot of articles on internet which explains these wizard kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot give you complete code to implement the task you want to implement, but can provide some starting point. Please go through the articles given below. Get back to us if you still have problems in implementing what you want after reading these.

1. [Wizard control in .net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ak_wizard.aspx)
2. [Asp.net and Vb.net wizard](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/wizard-vb.aspx)
3. [Wizard control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/wizard_control_yasin.aspx)

I found all these in a simple google search.